# Calling function from jQuery Dialog Form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When I click on this checkbox (inside the Modal form)

```
<input id="selectallcreate" type="checkbox" value="1" name="selectallcreate">
```

It will always return **False** using this code

```
if ($('#selectallcreate').is(':checked') == true){};
```

Also this code will work perfectly on any page that are **NOT** modal.  Other then that the modal form operates perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure in your DOM that there's only ONE instance of id `selectallcreate`.  You might be surprised to find that you have two. It's happened to me.  I'd say, try locating the checkbox by  `$('QueryToGetDialogDiv').find("#selectallcreate")`, so you can be sure you're grabbing the correct div.

Comment: I am sure jQuery is not cloning any fields in the dialog. It would defeat the whole purpose.. $('#selectallcreate') is way better than using $('QueryToGetDialogDiv').find("#selectallcreate").

Comment: I tried changing it to class="selectallcreate" and its working.

Comment: FYI: removed the jQuery part cloning to make the answer more universal as maybe the page creator accidentally put in two of the same IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shared looks fine. It should work fine as long as there are no other script errors.

[**DEMO here**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/cGJrr/2/)

Please try the demo and let us know if it is different from your code.

Comment: its because I was using ID and I add other instance of it.  Thanks for the demo

Comment: If you take `<input id="selectallcreate" type="checkbox" value="1" name="selectallcreate">Checkbox outside the popup` to just above the `id="dialog-modal"` div in your jsFiddle, you will see it fail in the same way as described.

Comment: @DMCS Can you edit the fiddle and share the link.. it worked fine when I moved the checkbox outside the popup.

Comment: No moved, copied to create a second instance of the same ID.  Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/cGJrr/3/